# Can not add an array item to an existing array at the start of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to add a new array item to the start of an existing array and get an error. I am trying to add a new array item to the array that is constructed on the fly. The example code below causes an error using the unshift operation.

The array that I want to insert to is  `lRtn.document.mainTemplate.item.item`s and I am using lodash to iterate over the parameter `_pUrls` and for each `url` I am creating a new array item and want to push the new array item to the existing array `lRtn.document.mainTemplate.item.items` leaving the existing array content in place.

The error is get is

```
Argument of type '{ type: string; description: string; source: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ type: string; duration: number; contentType?: undefined; content?: undefined; } | { type: string; contentType: string; content: string; duration?: undefined; }'.
  Type '{ type: string; description: string; source: any; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ type: string; contentType: string; content: string; duration?: undefined; }': contentType, content
```

The code that I have tried is here below, any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

```
export async function createAPLADirectiveBookReviews(
  _pUrls: any,
  _pFollowOn: string,
) {

  const lDescription = 'review';

  const lRtn = {
    type: constants.APLA.directiveType,
    token: constants.APLA.token,
    document: {
      version: '0.91',
      type: 'APLA',
      description: 'This document demonstrates key components used to create audio responses.',
      mainTemplate: {
        parameters: ['payload'],
        item: {
          type: 'Sequencer',
          description: 'Play this audio back in sequence',
          items: [
            {
              type: 'Silence',
              duration: 1500,
            },
            {
              type: 'Speech',
              contentType: 'PlainText',
              content: _pFollowOn,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    datasources: {
    },
  };

  // iterate over the urls and add them to the list
  _.forEach(_pUrls, function (url) {

    let lArrayItem = { 'type': 'Audio', 'description': lDescription, 'source': url };

    lRtn.document.mainTemplate.item.items.unshift(lArrayItem);

    });

  return lRtn;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAfTgMyhEcBEAbCATAQwGcALTAbgChKBTAD0ljmIE8A7AYxQFdOZgIbOByg0CMGgEEACgBlJAEWCiO-AG40AQhAgBrAEo01wGgHciACkpxEYAKpRsRAFzM2LADTXbAMQjZcUwB5NlciGChgNgBzLwBKOABvahsOQXC4bAUaIhFgMH5BOABeOAByUWMzMqpvNLYM7H0YIVLkmxsAek64GBYwGld68II2GCIAOhl5CbxlGlVgDQAVfpovDrhu3r0aUOF0mFHxqblJCZhdtg2OvAgObhA9mFd2zbgNKCIBfbKABgmAE4AIxlG6bPoDVxlaaSMHeTZ4HJ5Ao-aHLEjAIhwO4PJ5jHE0ECHKDiHJwXQ0FgHcCCZ7Y7hEGh4HbCURk5jcOYQOCiIiQBo5Cbw95wEAEKLLIlgbBk14I95gAikp4SL6uADaZSVLFwBDwZQAuuD3sAJCB5aKIWtoQBlGgAR24ew4NCgIqtNiRuUiqME0OksupMEx2IIXIEcAARgQOLo4FE4EynS6aB7PWaiS44BqFZ63p7rVDyrbgNhU+nC17uKTCvtgQBWP5-E2egC+ratBarvRtJYGCxIlar9QkY1WxbKgYlbCldBgw8Lo+ergQYD8AQgwWueatHd3m2NB7g+9Fp465694mIEBrruz3fPbdqXR6ZrVHIgn16JBocBrThuCy+osiGRKsmBmRYjA3gIBMyDQAAorGJAWGuDhOB4PB8D8cAWABCTJAq5bwNgkhQKSLAAJLmiUSTlJCabQpIEYQGC5TeiidZlK4WTIr6dZYWURC3lAro8f+jgni+HRNC0sz3I8zwTOKkrSrKEgTJmIBaeaky8KQwDIDAFhkRRBDUeacQyTYbbWSkvI0DANZCHJbBUG2QA)

Comment: I added these two attributes to the array and the error is gone, but I don't want these in the array item structure, why do I need them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript infers the type of the `lRtn.document.mainTemplate.item.items` array as an array of this union type (except I've put the properties in the same order in both of them; TypeScript doesn't care about property order):

```
{
    type: string;
    duration: number;
    contentType?: undefined;
    content?: undefined;
} | {
    type: string;
    duration?: undefined;
    contentType: string;
    content: string;
}
```

That means all members **must** match one of those two object shapes. But the object you're trying to put in the array doesn't match, it has this shape:

```
{
    type: string;
    description: string;
    source: any;
}
```

That doesn't have `duration` (which it would need to match the first type of the union) and also doesn't have `contentType` or `content` (which it would need for the second type of the union). So you can't put it in that array.

You need to either give an explicit type the `items` array that makes those properties options, or make your `lArrayItem` object fit the shape of one of those union types, so it fits into the array.

The best way to explicitly give a type to that `items` array would be to define a type for `lRtn`:

```
interface ItemType {
    type: string;
    duration?: number;
    contentType?: string;
    content?: string;
}
interface ReturnType {
    document: {
        version: string;
        type: string;
        description: string;
        mainTemplate: {
            parameters: string[];
            item: {
                type: string;
                description: string;
                items: ItemType[];
            };
        };
    },
    dataSources: {
        // ...
    }
};
```

(probably in smaller parts than that) and use `const lRtn: ReturnType = ...` to assign a type to the whole thing.

But you can also do it with an `as` expression on the array:

```
interface ItemType {
    type: string;
    duration?: number;
    contentType?: string;
    content?: string;
}
// ...
const lRtn = {
          // ...
          items: [
              {
                  type: 'Silence',
                  duration: 1500,
              },
              {
                  type: 'Speech',
                  contentType: 'PlainText',
                  content: _pFollowOn,
              },
          ] as ItemType[], // <<============
          // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to typescript so this is somewhat confusing.

Comment: @EthanRichardson - (I've updated the answer a bit.) FWIW, I suggest not just trying to pick it up as you go along. Take a couple of hours to go through a decent introductory course, it'll save you time in the long run. :-) Happy coding!